# how can i remotely control my android tablet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, android, tablet, remote-control

device // tablet - nexus 7 2013 wi-fi model
android version - 6.0.1
rooted - no

device // laptop
operating system - microsoft windows 10 pro 64-bit

so with this little info about my devices

how can i remotely control my nexus 7 2013 from my windows 10 laptop?
I want to be able to remotely control and check my android apps without using a android virtual machine nor android emulator

Answer (score 0):

A program named Teamviewer will help if you have root access on your tablet.
Without root access it seems to be impossible.